# How does search engine mapping sites without links to certain pages?

Tags: search-engine

How search engines can map pages in sites without links to them [pages] ? how can they search in domains such as `www.zippyshare.com` and find links for download page in that site or other uploading sites?
Thanks.

Comment: Search engines traditionally use web crawlers to find new pages. If there is no link to a certain page in a website, the web crawler cannot find it unless someone manually adds it to the web crawler's database. Some services, like Twitter, use special APIs that link to Google so that the search engine can display Tweets and other dynamically created content.

Comment: Oh another point I forgot to add: search engines like Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc. tend to look for a robots.txt file in the root directory of a website. That file tells the any web crawlers accessing the site to include or exclude certain pages/sections on a website. You can also include a sitemap for the search engines to reference.